# Callback in ios not returning for authentication

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm using [swifter](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) to grab the access token

```
swifter.authorize(with: URL(string: "callback://")!, presentFrom: self, success: { accessToken, response in
        print("HELLO")
        print(accessToken)
        // ...
    }, failure: { error in
        // ...
    })
```

I can log in successfully because the app opens up SFSafariViewController, but then I'm not directed back to my app, and the success callback is never being called

here's the code for swifter, I see that presentFrom is suppose to be SFSafariViewController, but the delgate methods for SFSafariViewController aren't being triggered

```
 public func authorize(with callbackURL: URL, presentFrom presentingViewController: UIViewController? , success: TokenSuccessHandler?, failure: FailureHandler? = nil) {
    self.postOAuthRequestToken(with: callbackURL, success: { token, response in
        var requestToken = token!
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .SwifterCallbackNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
            presentingViewController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let url = notification.userInfo![CallbackNotification.optionsURLKey] as! URL

            let parameters = url.query!.queryStringParameters
            requestToken.verifier = parameters["oauth_verifier"]

            self.postOAuthAccessToken(with: requestToken, success: { accessToken, response in
                self.client.credential = Credential(accessToken: accessToken!)
                success?(accessToken!, response)
                }, failure: failure)
        }

        let authorizeURL = URL(string: "oauth/authorize", relativeTo: TwitterURL.oauth.url)
        let queryURL = URL(string: authorizeURL!.absoluteString + "?oauth_token=\(token!.key)")!

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) , let delegate = presentingViewController as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
            let safariView = SFSafariViewController(url: queryURL)
            safariView.delegate = delegate
            presentingViewController?.present(safariView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(queryURL)
        }
    }, failure: failure)
}
```

Comment: did you evere find the solution to this? I'm struggling with this right now too

Answer (score 0):

does it just wait and say "redirecting you back to the application" but never actually goes back to application?

You need to add both of these functions to the Appdelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    Swifter.handleOpenURL(url)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    Swifter.handleOpenURL(url as URL)

    return true
}
```

also try look at this for further assistance: [How to Authorize Twitter with Swifter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005919/how-to-authorize-twitter-with-swifter)